# Twitter sharing problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using TwitterOAuth to publish the details of my application on to the Twitter. It works fine on simulator but on device it is showing the message "Sorry, this page doesn't exist".

Plz help me to find the solution...!!!

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. A quick Google suggests that TwitterOAuth is a PHP framework, not iPhone. You'll have to explain what you're doing, what you've tried and what you want to achieve better. Some code would help, too.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington: First of all thanx for ur response and, There is nothing as big to look into but some times when I launch my app on my iPhone and further tap the button for twitter, I find the message "Sorry, this page doesn't exist" from the twitter server. Note that I don't find the problem all the times but some times, may the reason be that server is busy or some thing else but for few days it is working fine(don't know what was the issue there).

Answer (score 1):

check ShareKit: http://www.getsharekit.com/